# How to properly link PayPal subscription to my database?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm having some problems understanding the proper way to go about linking an account to someone's user account for my website, for my website I'm using a subscription based system that uses recurring payments. What I'm having a problem understanding is how to properly figure out which account that payment is relative to.

At first I though about using the `payer_email` to link an account and a paypal account together, however after somet thinking I realized that if the user was to change their e-mail then we'd run into some payment problems. (They would still pay, but their account would never be updated).

Then I thought, hmm, what about `payer_id` however some research brought up this statement:

> As others have said, payer_id can be used to identify a Paypal
>   account. HOWEVER! -- a single Paypal account can have several
>   payer_ids associated with it, one for each credit card or funding
>   source used by that account. Because of this, a given Paypal account
>   does NOT map one-to-one to a single payer_id.

Then I thought about a transaction id; However this changes with each payment, so now I'm sitting here completely clueless as to the best way to map a paypal subscription to my account database.

---

What I need to do:

1. When a payment comes in, find the account relative to the payment:
2. Update that accounts information.

Comment: Please provide reasoning for down-voting a legitimate question? Thanks.

Comment: Good question, well worded, and well researched. Voted up. :) You helped me from not going down the payer_id route!

Answer (score 0):

Check the IPN of PAYPAL (Instant Payment Notification)

you can set the notification URL to return back some data.

FORM Eg:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="test.com/paypal.php?action=upgrade_plan_success">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="test.com/paypal.php?action=cancel">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="test.com/notify_paypal.php">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$user_id"> //any unique thing about customer
```

when ever the payment is done it will notify you in url **notify_paypal.php** mention above. It will return some array, in that we have our custom value which we can use to manipulate database..

so imp is

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$user_id"> //any unique thing about customer
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I understand generating custom variables, because I have done it in the past for applying status' or adding items to a specified user; However this time around I'm trying to figure out how to link a recurring payment to a user. I won't be able to pass a custom field besides for the very first time. Other times the payments are automatically generated. 

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you? -- `Please note, this method works fine for buy-now buttons`

Comment: currently its working for me every time custom variable will come along with notification

Comment: for testing do 1 day recurring payment and check what all variables are comming